# Toolbar Color won't change in API <23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I used this code to change my Toolbar in my lollipop device.

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(
    ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorWhite));
```

But when I tried to use my application in API19.
The toolbar color won't change.

Comment: Try this `toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR")); `

Comment: "COLOR"? what should i put in there.

Comment: example :
`toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.red)));`

Comment: Spelling and formatting improved.

Comment: Use `AppCompat` and use `colorPrimary` in your `style.xml`.

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable is depcrecated..

Comment: toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.red)));
this is not working.. :'(

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int color = getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

edit: right since the API has changed and a deprication has hapened for now i would suggest something lke this

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW){
            //set using depricated code [one i put earlier]
}else{
            //set using latest api;s [ones which youre currently using]
}
```

Comment: that's what i did. getResources.getColor is deprecated

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor()
is something like that.

Comment: yeah sorry forgot about api23, try the edit...ive used something like this to handle notifications in lollipop, untill appcompat leverages something new.